# Unable to restore "Acronis" image file of my System drive to Target drive due to activation of TPM 2.0 in my BIOS

Tags: lock

I made the error of switching from "Discrete TPM 1.2 to Firmware TPM 2.0 in order to upgrade my Windows 10 Pro to W11. Foolishly I ignored the warning given by the BIOS configuration.

"Intel PTT is a hardware TPM 2.0 implementation integrated in Intel ME/CSME/TXE for credential storage and key management. The firmware TPM key will be stored in Intel ME data region once you enable Intel PTT and Windows BitLocker for drive encryption. Please note that when the recovery key is lost or when the BIOS ROM chip is replaced, the system will not boot into the operating system and the data will stay encrypted and cannot be restored."

I now find that I cannot restore from any of my "Acronis" backup image files to a specific "system" target drive. Acronis tells me that "even though I can complete a restore function from any particular image file, it will not boot from the target restore drive" .

I read about a "key" to unlock the volume on which the image file was saved, but I never wrote down any key. I was also never given the opportunity to find, read or record a key.

In all other ways all my hard drives are accessible when operating normally under Windows 10 Pro. Bitlocker IS NOT activated for any of my drives

The problem is I have lost restore functionality to a system target drive of my backup  Acronis images. This also applies to any new Acronis backup images.

My mother board is an ASUS ROC Strix Z370E.

I  returned my BIOS setting to Discrete TMP 1.2, but of course to no avail as the impact on Acronis Recovery function appears to be permanent.

If all else fails can I reformat my "system" drive and re install Windows to reset Acronis Image  functionality to normal.

Is there some way that I can retrieve the KEY from the INTEL partition, even though Bitlocker was never activated?

Comment: Can you use the ASUS CrashFree BIOS 3 to recover the BIOS back to original form?

Comment: Can you restore existing images to another system, or to an external HDD mounted on the Windows 11 PC? If so, you can at least access the data. For the future, test new images made with other tools, such as Macrium Reflect, to see if they can be restored to the Windows 11 box.

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I have yet to determine if it is a BIOS issue following my Discrete TMP1.2 vs Firmware TMP 2.0 reversal problem. Even though Bitlocker was not activated, I had never seen this Acronis warning before and only after the TMP issue. All Acronis previous "restore" images have worked and successfully restored my system drives on this machine and my second server. I have obtained a copy of Macrium Respect and intend to create a test image to determine if it can be used for restore. I also successfully create a system drive image using AOMEI.